# Why are my buttons unresponsive in my Android Studio app?

Tags: java, android

Why isn't my android studio app switching screens once a button is clicked?
whenever trying to press a button in order to switch to my next activity, the app does not respond.

```
package com.example.sceabblecalculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnLogIn;
    Button btnSignUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        btnLogIn = findViewById(R.id.logInButton);
        btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
        btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == btnLogIn.getId()){
            switchActivitiesLogIn();
        }
        if (view.getId() == btnSignUp.getId()){
            switchActivitiesSignUp();
        }
    }


    private void switchActivitiesLogIn() {
        Intent switchActivityIntent = new Intent(this, LogIn.class);
        startActivity(switchActivityIntent);
    }

    private void switchActivitiesSignUp() {
        Intent switchActivityIntent = new Intent(this, SignUp.class);
        startActivity(switchActivityIntent);
    }
}
```

attaching my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logInButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="log in" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="sign up" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SceabbleCalculator"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".FirstActivityGpt"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".NewPlayerActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PlayersActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreen"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SceabbleCalculator" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreenActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".home_screen"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SceabbleCalculator" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GameActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUp"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LogIn"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Ran my entire code via chatGpt and they said my code doesn't contain any errors, but yet my buttons are unresponsive.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Try adding some logging to the top of your `onClick` method to start narrowing down the problem.

Comment: can you, please, also copy your `activity_first.xml` file?

Comment: ` ` `// 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logInButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="log in" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="sign up" />

</LinearLayout>` ` ` @AlexanderDadukin

Answer (score 1):

Have you register Login activity and signup activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find this implementation very confusing ... The approach that I would is the following:

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnLogIn;
    private Button btnSignUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        btnLogIn = findViewById(R.id.logInButton);
        btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
        btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               switchActivitiesLogIn();
            }
        });
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switchActivitiesSignUp();
            }
        });
    }

    private void switchActivitiesLogIn() {
        Intent switchActivityIntent = new Intent(this, LogIn.class);
        startActivity(switchActivityIntent);
    }

    private void switchActivitiesSignUp() {
        Intent switchActivityIntent = new Intent(this, SignUp.class);
        startActivity(switchActivityIntent);
    }
}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, please also add the activity_first XML code in your post.

Comment: it doesn't compile, the { after the onClickListener is not an expected token.

Comment: Sorry about that, please try again @Michael_fr

Comment: Still did not work I'm afraid. Added the xml code into my post.

Comment: While I agree this is a better style, it isn't his problem.  What he has is awkward, but a working way of doing it.  It's more likely a manifest error

Comment: I started a new project with the original and it opens up for me. I don't believe that it is a manifest error, otherwise we would not be able to build the project, but let's see. @Michael_fr can you also add the manifest file

Comment: Added the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I am using viewBinding for simplicity. You can enable it by adding the below code in `build.gradle(:app)`.

```
android {
   ...
     buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

### FirstActivity.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.umesh.testapp.databinding.ActivityFirstBinding


class FirstActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityFirstBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityFirstBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.logInButton.setOnClickListener {
           Toast.makeText(this, "logInButton click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           val switchLoginIntent = Intent(this, LogIn::class.java)
           startActivity(switchLoginIntent)
        }

        binding.signUpButton.setOnClickListener {
          Toast.makeText(this, "signUpButton click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val switchSignUpIntent = Intent(this, SignUp::class.java)
            startActivity(switchSignUpIntent)
        }
    }
}
```

### activity_first.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logInButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="log in" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="sign up" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this and let me know if still facing issue. Make sure to define `LogIn` and `SignUp` activity in AndroidManifest.xml file